# Why do I get a REFRESH_COMPLETED_WITH_UNCERTAIN_ACCOUNT?

Tags: yodlee

It's not clear to me why I'm getting this error: REFRESH_COMPLETED_WITH_UNCERTAIN_ACCOUNT

The authentication workflow went through, but I can't get any summaries for the added site.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a site , all the different types of accounts under the provided credentials will be added. Like - saving, credit card account, loan account etc.

When the refresh is completed but there is a failure in refresh for one of the different types of account present for that site for a user because of either data agent or Site [error](http://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes)  then this status is set. Hence  this status has to be treated same as REFRESH_COMPLETED and you should be able to get summary details.

Comment: That's the problem, I get no summaries at all. I tried treating it as REFRESH_COMPLETED with no success, i.e., login is successful but I don't get any Item Summaries.

Comment: To my point, here's the result of getItemSummariesForSite after REFRESH_COMPLETED_WITH_UNCERTAIN_ACCOUNT:

    {"key":{}}

Comment: I believe you are testing on developer.yodlee.com. can you provide the siteAccountID please.

Comment: I'm in the pilot program, accessing live actual data, not developer dummy accounts.

Comment: Here's the ID: 10295854 - right now it gives a login failure, probably due to the MFA request which wasn't provided during the refresh cycle. But following the MFA workflow, I'm able to get a LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: In addition, right now this site which is MFA for sure is giving me this: siteRefreshInfo.siteRefreshMode.refreshMode = "NORMAL".